# Converting com.google.datastore.v1.Entity to/from com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Both classes, [com.google.datastore.v1.Entity](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/datastore/v1/Entity.html) and [com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/cloud/datastore/Entity.html), apparently work as Entity in Datastore. Why have two classes to do the same thing, and how to convert one to another?

I'm using two libraries, and each one uses one of the Entity classes. That's why I need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the [Java Entity](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/cloud/datastore/Entity.html) is easier to use than the [protocol buffer Entity](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/datastore/v1/Entity.html).  e.g. `Entity.getString("property_name")` vs `v1.Entity.getPropertiesMap().get("property_name").getStringValue()`.  Similar for the builders.

To convert from an v1.Entity to an Entity, you can simply use `Entity.fromPb`.  I don't see a method to easily go from an Entity to a v1.Entity without serializing the Entity.